# Trying to change connection settings on SoundCloud user profile

Tags: c#, soundcloud

When you go to your user profile in SoundCloud and choose connections you can control stuff like automatically posting when you upload new sounds.

I'm creating a C# application and I would like to be able to manage those settings however the documentation isn't much help in this case. Using fiddler I was able to see that for instance, if I try to enable automatic posting of new sounds the following POST is executed:

```
POST http://soundcloud.com/connect/twitter/<connection_id_here> HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://soundcloud.com/settings/connections
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*, */*, application/json, text/javascript, soundcloud/json
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MASEJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: soundcloud.com
Content-Length: 158
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: <huge_cookie_info_here>

_method=put&authenticity_token=<auth_token_here>&external_identity%5Bpost_tracks%5D=1&external_identity%5Bpost_favorites%5D=0
```

I'm trying to replicate the above code withouth success. Here's what I'm doing:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("_method","put"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("authenticity_token","<auth_token_here>"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("external_identity[post_tracks]","1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("external_identity[post_favorites]","0"),
});

var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://soundcloud.com/connect/twitter/<connection_id_here>", content);
```

Even though the response status is OK the connection settings remain unchanged.

Anyone care to help?

Regards,

Eduardo Serrano

Answer (score 0):

The process to change the connections is described here:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#connections

Comment: I've already been through the docs and unless I missed something they do not address what I'm trying to accomplish. They explain how to get the list of existing connections, how to get a particular connection and how to create a new connection. They do not explain how to change the settings of existing connections. By settings I mean connection options such as automatically share new sounds, etc.